# Databinding ContextMenu MenuItems to an existing Menu's MenuItems

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

Given a menu named "main", I want to write markup like the following:

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=Items}" />
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

This doesn't work - it seems to create an empty ContextMenu.

This is the markup for the Menu:

```
<Menu Name="main" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="Close" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="_Options">
        <MenuItem Header="_Show status bar" IsCheckable="True" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Group numbers" IsCheckable="True" />
    </MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="_About" />
```

Comment: can you post the XAML where "main" is included?

Comment: I don't have it with me at the moment. Does it matter? "main" is a Menu with MenuItems, and it displays properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution [here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-data-binding/1819/Reuse-WPF-MenuItem) is sufficient for my needs, even though it doesn't use databinding, but an array of menuitems as a resource.

It would still be interesting theoretically to know if this is possible somehow.

Comment: It can't be possible. A MenuItem is a FrameworkElement object. Therefore it has only one logical parent. It cannot have both the menu and the context-menu as its parents. The solution in the link you gave generates an array of menu items every time the resource is referenced, and therefore the menu items are not shared between menus.